# Check on undefined variable causes fatal error

Tags: php, symfony, php-8, symfony6

I'm updating a very old website from a symfony 2 version to a symfony 6 version and I'm rewriting a bunch of the code.
I'm encountering a problem when checking a variable that has not be defined.
It causes a critical error when I'm expecting a simple warning.
For example:

```
if($testvar)
   echo "test";
```

I expect this to create a Warning, but not a fatal error. I've also tested this code online with some php tools and it seems its not creating a fatal error.

If it can help here is the precise error I'm getting from Symfony:

> CRITICA| REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception ErrorException: "Warning: Undefined variable $testvar"

I'm using Symfony6 with PHP8.1.5

Perhaps there is some configuration at PHP level to be done ? Like not considering warning as critical error ?

Thanks

Comment: Symfony likely uses its own error handler, so you would have to "ignore" such warnings in there when it wants to throw an exception.

Comment: That's a good lead but I cannot find where to make such a change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a simple solution:
changing the error reporting inside php code did the trick
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_WARNING);

I still got the warnings as logs, but its not stopping the scripts from running anymore